# Add Attachment through Mandril templates

Tags: ruby-on-rails, http-headers, actionmailer, mandrill

We are using Mandril wrapper for mail templates. We have integrated SMTP headers to pass variables to Mandril https://mandrill.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/205582117-Using-SMTP-Headers-to-customize-your-messages#custom-header-reference

But it doesn't include headers for attachments . How can I pass attachments.

I tried Headers like this

```
headers['X-MC-Attachments'] = attachments
```

attachments contains array of hash with proper format required by mandril templates.

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

There's no custom header for sending attachments with Mandrill. If you're using ActionMailer, you can use the `attachments` method shown here: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html#adding-attachments